# Inconsistent results when subquery is used

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the following running transaction:

```
begin tran t
select 1 from T(updlock) where id = 'id1'
waitfor delay '00:00:10'
update T set value = 'new' where id = 'id1'
commit tran t
```

If within the `waitfor` delay I launch the following request:

```
select value from T(updlock) where id = 'id1'
```

This request blocks until transaction `t` completes, and then returns the result `new` as expected.

But if instead I launch the following request:

```
select value from T where id in (select id from T(updlock) where id = 'id1')
```

This request is also blocked by `t`, but then the result is `old`.

Why is that?

---

### Annex: execution plans

- [First select](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyubUDdfx)
- [Second select](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkxqHPuzg)

Comment: are you running selects after the transaction completed or prior to that.since this part is confusing `within the wait delay` and you also stated `transaction t completes`..Can you also share execution plan of two selects

Comment: OK, edited to clarify.

Comment: that should not be possible.Can you add execution plan and paste it here

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @TheGameiswar Reproduced on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @TT.:Not able to reproduce on SQL2012,

Comment: @illedr:please share some repro script

Comment: Added execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible. I'm not sure why you think it wouldn't be. [`S` locks are not blocked by `U` locks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT T1.value
FROM   T T1
WHERE  T1.id IN (SELECT T2.id
                 FROM   T(updlock) T2
                 WHERE  T2.id = 'id1')
```

has an [implied predicate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2009/04/28/implied-predicates-and-query-hints/) though that is not relevant to the behaviour you see. The execution plan is the same as below (with the seek on 'id1' copied to the T1 branch and an uncorrelated sub query)

```
SELECT T1.value
FROM   T T1
WHERE  T1.id = 'id1'
       AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   T(updlock) T2
                   WHERE  T2.id = 'id1')
```

[image]

Your `SELECT` query in the first window takes an `UPDLOCK` on the row and holds it for 10 seconds - however this is compatible with the `S` lock required by the seek on `T1` in window 2 so that seek emits a row with the `value` column to the nested loops operator. Then the nested loops requests a row from its second input (the seek on `T2`). This has the `UPDLOCK` hint so is blocked.

Eventually the first window converts its `UPDLOCK` to an `X` lock, releases its lock and the seek on `T2` is unblocked. It then emits a row (with no columns so completely unaffected by the fact that `value` has changed). This means that the semi join condition (`EXISTS` predicate) is met and the original row is passed along to the root iterator and output.

Comment: I understand. But why is the optimizer allowed to pull up the seek on 'id1' to the outer query if that leads to bypass the lock logic? From my (naive/non-expert) perspective, in the first window, the outer query input depends on the inner query output, so there is some sequencing here. That's why I expected the inner query's `updlock` lock to be released _at the time_ the outer query input is fed, and so the outer query to run _after_ the transaction update, and return the updated value.

Comment: @lledr - As I stated in my answer this isn't the cause of the behaviour you see. Even if the predicate wasn't pushed into T1 and it scanned all rows and used a correlated sub query the same behaviour could still occur as the scan on T1 just takes S locks and the update lock isn't taken until the seek on T2., In general the optimiser is free to optimise out branches with locking hints though. e.g. `select *
from 
(
select value from T(updlock) where id = 'id1'
) t
where 1 =0` doesn't lock the row at all.